# Returning a Secure "Winning Code" to User

Tags: php, jquery, authentication, encryption, encoding

This is probably a very basic/introductory thing, but let me paint a scenario:

Let's say I'm using jQuery to do some sort of mini quiz game on my site.  The user clicks the correct answer, and then a window pops up with a secret "winner's code" that they can redeem elsewhere.

How can I generate the winner's code so that it doesn't just appear in the HTML and in a way that users cannot reverse-engineer it (at least without considerable effort)?

I mean, if I just generated an encoded string containing their username and some sort of additional information only I know, that would work, right?  Or MD5 hash or something, but how do I make it so the winner's code itself doesn't appear in the HTML, and only when the correct answer is chosen?

Thank you for any suggested reading/tutorials/assistance/advice you can offer.

Comment: read up on ajax...send game info to server and let server generate the return code when your logic allows it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of questions there.

**1) How to generate a secure code:**

if you are implementing a 'winner code' you could use an hashed iv + secret + user information, or some signing mechanism.  You could also implement a code expiry time on the server so that you could further raise the bar, if necessary.

**2) Getting the code to the winning user:**

If you don't want the code to appear in the html, then you want to use ajax to get it.  Then inject the code into the DOM where you want to display it.  Further, you should be using a secure SSL channel to do this so that you guard against sniffing.  Even further, consider some kind of 'one-time' token so that a man-in-the-middle cannot repost your code request and receive the same win code.

Hope this gives you something to consider.

Comment: What I was really looking for was the DOM injection of code.  No one else specifically said it directly and instead alluded to AJAX and whatnot.  I don't know why I didn't think of it, but it should solve all my problems, so I am awarding you with the answer.  If I can pick two answers, I'll be giving the other to houby.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you just want the code to appear whenever the correct answer is chosen?

If so, just have a PHP page to which you send the answer the user chose in a GET/POST variable. Then, have that PHP page show the code only if the answer was correct. That way it won't be in the HTML if the answer is incorrect.

So for example, your PHP page would look like:

```
<?php
if ($_GET["answer"] == "correct_answer") {
  echo "give the code here";
} else {
  echo "sorry the answer was incorrect";
}
?>
```

Additionally, if you want the above to appear in a javascript popup or something, [fetch it using Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Wouldn't the user be able to see the PHP page you're passing variables to (e.g. "testanswer.php") and then go into their address bar and just try every multiple choice on the page until it spits out a winner's code?  For example, they manually type www.site.com/testanswer.php?guess=answer1 and change 'answer1' to anything else until they get a hit.

Comment: @daveycroqet: yes. If you want every user to have only one chance, modify the PHP page to check if that user tried before (you could either have everybody login, or check their IP and allow one IP only one try, ...).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I an upvoting this as it also helped quite a bit, though I don't particularly want to limit people's # of attempts; rather, I just want to prevent ease of abuse.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for the game to be secure at all, all evaluation of winning MUST be done on a server and all redeemable codes must be uniquely created on the server and sent to the client.

It simply cannot be done on the client in a secure fashion because ALL javascript code is available for inspection by anyone.  There are means of obscuring javascript code to make it more of a pain for someone to reverse engineer, but that cannot stop a determined hacker - it can only slow them down or slightly deter them.  The only place where your code/algorithms for evaluating the results of the game is safe and free from manipulation is on your server.

Even then, you probably need to do something to keep one user from getting a redeemable code and then sharing it with lots of other people or getting the right answer and then having someone else write a script that submits the right answer to your server to generate limitless codes.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Could you, perchance, provide a link to one of these methods to obscure javascript?  I may not implement it, but I'd like to take a look nonetheless.  I could Google, but I got the impression that you had a specific method in mind.  I'd like to take a look, if that's the case.

Comment: @daveycroqet - I don't use obscuration (seems pointless to me) so I don't have a recommended option.